# Why are RET and C-j flipped on AucTeX?

Tags: auctex

Before installing AucTeX, when I would edit `.tex` files with emacs, it would automatically indent when I would press enter after typing a line such as `\begin{equation}`. Typing `C-j` would cause a linebreak without indenting. But after installing AucTeX, the behavior is now reversed - pressing enter breaks the line without indenting, and pressing `C-j` breaks the line and indents it.

First I wanted to confirm that it's not just me, and make sure it's not a problem with my installation of AucTeX. Second, I wanted to see how to get it so that AucTeX breaks and indents the line when I press enter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to configure your .emacs the proper way. This is how [auctex documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html) explains it

> You can explicitely indent single lines, usually by pressing , or marked regions by calling indent-region on it. If you have auto-fill-mode enabled and a line is broken while you type it, Emacs automatically cares about the indentation in the following line. If you want to have a similar behavior upon typing , you can customize the variable TeX-newline-function and change the default of newline which does no indentation to newline-and-indent which indents the new line or reindent-then-newline-and-indent which indents both the current and the new line.

You should put in your emacs something like:

```
(setq TeX-newline-function 'newline-and-indent)
```